# Deleted my MainViewController.m

Tags: xcode

I was working on my project in Xcode and I accidentally deleted my .m file. I managed to recover all the that I deleted however my .m file is red and I can't find a way to type anything on the file. Nothing happens if I click on it once and if i double click it just says  no editor. If someones how to fix this I'd appreciate the help!

Comment: I guess now those .m would be in trash or in your project folder only. You can add them by dragging them into your project or from "Add Files".

Comment: But is there any way I can just create a new .m file because i only have pictures of my .m file.

Comment: I file in red means that Xcode expects the file to exist, but it isn't there. You need to recreate the file in that location.

Comment: What do you mean by "pictures of my .h file"? Better you delete .h also and add .h and .m with same name.

Comment: I mean that i took a print of my screen before I accidentally deleted my file. How do I add the new files?

Comment: Project Navigator (Cmd + 1)->right click-> New file..

Answer (score 0):

Add the file to you project again.

Answer (score 0):

If the file is deleted from the xcode project but still exists in the project folder on your drive , then click on the folder icon next as shown in the attached screenshot and provide the location on disk.

[image]